# Using multiple boundary conditions with NDEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I'm quite new to Mathematica and to Stack Exchange so I apologise if this question has already been answered.

I've recently been trying to solve a partial differential equation to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions with NDEigensystem. I'm trying to enter multiple boundary conditions into NDEigensystem but I keep getting the following error:

**NDEigensystem::dvlen: The function u[-x,y] does not have the same number of arguments as independent variables (3).**

The following is my code.

```
keyhole = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {{x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, 0.0001, 50}}];

NDEigensystem[{-y^2 (D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}]), u[-1/2, y] == u[1/2, y], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] ==  u[-x, y], x^2 + y^2 == 1]},u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] keyhole, 2]
```

I believe the error may be due to a syntax error with the DirichletCondition option or because I have too many boundary conditions.

I would really appreciate your input on what I'm doing wrong currently.

Thank you for your help.

**Update**
Based on @user21's comments, I was able to implement PeriodicBoundaryCondition to get the boundary conditions that I wanted. However, I am now encountering a new problem when I specify the domain **keyhole**. Whenever I set 0.0001<=y <= ymax, and ymax >= 100, I get the following error message:

```
Eigensystem::herm: The matrix SparseArray[Automatic,<<2>>,{1,{{<<1>>},{<<1>>}},{(lots of numbers here)}] is not Hermitian or real and symmetric
```

Is there a way that I can modify my code to allow me to increase the domain where the eigenfunction gets solved?

Thank you again for all your help. My updated code is as follows.

```
keyhole = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {{x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, 0.0001,100}}];
test = NDEigensystem[{-y^2 (D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}]),PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == -1/2,TranslationTransform[{1, 0}]],PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x^2 + y^2 == 1, Function[x, {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}}.x]]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] keyhole, 4];
Table[Plot3D[test[[2]][[i]], {x, y} \[Element] keyhole, PlotRange -> All,MeshStyle -> None, PlotLabel -> test[[1]][[i]], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}], {i, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: I think [`PeriodicBoundaryCondition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeriodicBoundaryCondition.html) might do what you want here.

Comment: What do you want to express with `DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == u[-x, y], x^2 + y^2 == 1]`?

Comment: @sr101studios Read the tutorial: Eigensystems with inhomogeneous Dirichlet conditions cannot be solved.

Comment: @user21 I used PeriodicBoundaryCondition and I got the code to work. For example, when I specify keyhole = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {{x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, 0.0001, ymax}}]  with ymax <= 100, it works. However, I encounter a problem for ymax > 100. I keep getting the error **Eigensystem::herm: The matrix SparseArray[Automatic,<<2>>,{1,{{<<1>>},{<<1>>}},{(lots of numbers here)}] is not Hermitian or real and symmetric**. Do you know what might be going on and how I can resolve this? I've edited my original post with the new code.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke, thank you for your help. I have slightly new issue now which I was wondering if you could help with. It's in my above comment and I've edited my initial post to describe it. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is necessary to use homogeneous boundary conditions. We can also investigate the influence of the size of the area along `y`, including `ymax=50` .

```
p[L_, n_] := 
 Block[{ymax = L, nmax = n}, 
  keyhole = 
   ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {{x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, 0.0001, ymax}}];
  {v, f} = 
   NDEigensystem[{-y^2 (D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}]), 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
    u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] keyhole, nmax];
  Table[Plot3D[f[[i]], {x, y} \[Element] keyhole, PlotRange -> All, 
    Mesh -> None, PlotLabel -> v[[i]], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}], {i, 1, nmax}]]
Table[p[L, 2], {L, {5, 10, 25, 50}}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you, Alex! I really appreciate your comments and your updating of the code. The plots looks brilliant. However, I'm not sure how the necessary boundary conditions are being implemented in your example. I think it's important for this system to have the boundary condition u[1/2, y] = u[-1/2, y] and the condition that on the unit circle, u[x,y] = u[-x,y]. However, I'm not sure if your code is implementing those conditions. Do you think it's possible to have boundary conditions like that in our region? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @sr101studios It is obvious that `u[1/2,y]=u[-1/2,y]=0` and `u[x,y]=u[-x,y]=0` at `x^2+y^2=1`,  all this is in `DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]`.