# Finding eigensystem using NDEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I am trying to calculate eigensystems for a matrix `Ap`, which I have provided an example of which in this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279016/define-a-matrix-with-derivative-variable-and-calculate-its-eigensystem). The matrix in general has a dependency on a variable `a` and its read

```
Ap[a_, kx_, ky_] := {0.5 a u1[kx, ky] + 3 kx u2[kx, ky] + 3 ky u2[kx, ky] + D[u2[kx, ky], kx], 2 kx u1[kx, ky] + 2 ky u1[kx, ky] - D[u1[kx, ky], kx] - 0.3 a kx u2[kx, ky]}
```

I then called

```
     {vals, vecs} = NDEigensystem[ Ap[1, kx, ky], {u1[kx, ky], u2[kx, ky]}, {kx, -3, 3}, {ky, -3, 3}, 10, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",  {"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}}}];
```

In addition, I have tried to incorporate the insertion of variable `a` in the matrix using the suggestion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198507/58680) as

```
p[a_, n_] := 
 Block[{aval = a, nmax = n}, {vals, vecs} = 
    NDEigensystem[
     Ap[aval, kx, ky], {u1[kx, ky], u2[kx, ky]}, {kx, -3, 3}, {ky, -3,
       3}, nmax, 
     Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}}}];
   Table[
    Plot3D[vecs[[i]], {kx, -3, 3}, {ky, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
     Mesh -> None, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
      AxesLabel -> {"kx", "ky", ""}], {i, 1, nmax}]
   ]
  p[1.0, 10]
```

Is there a possibility to generate `vals[a,kx,ky]`?

Comment: Try to Quit the kernel and try again. Your first example give a different error message for me.

Comment: You are right. The error disappeared after restarting the kernel. I have edited the question accordingly. Do you have any suggestions on getting two functions, `vals[a,kx,ky]` and `vecs[a,kx,ky]`? Based on my attempt above, I can get `vals` but don't have access to the `k` variables yet.